# Animating the HTML5 details element

Tags: html, animation, html-tag-details

Is it possible to animate the html5 details element **without** jQuery?

I have seen a few jQuery fallbacks around the web that animate the details element, but I **do not** want to use jQuery.

jQuery example that animates the details element:
http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/demos/details.html

Comment: Yes, it is possible. (jQuery is purely JavaScript so anything you can do with jQuery you can also do without it.)

Comment: @AdamJones Question updated.